# How to disable automatic zoom change in IE11 when moving window between different monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, zoom, internet-explorer-11

On Windows 8.1 I use Internet Explorer 11 and I also got my notebook with 13" screen and LCD monitor with 24" screen.

When I move IE windows between screens, IE automatically changes the zoom "to preserve same font size" on screens with different DPI. This is unwanted, I don't want to have 100% on one screen and 125% on the other. Is there a way how to disable this, even using registry fix?

Note this is [already reported on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/804990/internet-explorer-11-auto-zoom-feature-within-ie11) with no proper answer.

Comment: Do you know if this affects browser apps like SAP, which is somewhat notorious for only working at 100% zoom?

Comment: still no solution?

Comment: Does this happen with other browsers too?

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

- Open Internet Explorer on the Desktop.......
- Tools → Internet Options → Advanced (tab on top) → Accessibility
- CHECK the  box "Reset zoom level for new windows and tabs"
- Click APPLY
- Click OK

I got the answer from:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/disable-auto-zoom-in-ie11/ced7d289-2758-4e03-be77-a48cea1b60b9?page=1

Answer (score 0):

Found this online and works on my IE11:

Set the following registry keys:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom

ZoomDisabled [DWORD] = 1

ZoomFactor   [DWORD] = 186a0 (this resets the zoom to 100%)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (IE 11, Windows 8.1, high DPI screen). It just disables the manual zoom changes, the automatic zooming is still in effect.